# A forward slash at end of URL breaks CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I'm developing a website and when I put a forward slash `/` at the end of a URL, the CSS file doesn't get read.

Example:

- This URL runs perfectly fine: `www.localhost.com/index.php`
- This URL ignores the CSS file: `www.localhost.com/index.php/`

In short, the forward slash ruins the design of the website.

How can I fix this problem? I searched for a [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) solution, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try to include your CSS file using an absolute path (e.g., *http://...*) or a path starting from your webroot (e.g., */css/yourfile.css*)

Otherwise, you need to disallow (or redirect) requests to *index.php/* in *index.php* via .htaccess (or server configuration).

Comment: thank you for answering, it is kind a okay but it's not, it fix the problem of retaining the design but the link did not work, it becomes file within a file www.localhost.com/index.php/home.php

Answer (score 3):

Just use a "/" before setting the location for the CSS in your *index.html* header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css"/>
```

That way your *index.html* will look for the file from the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the trailing slash, except for the root and existing folders:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\.php|\.html)/$  /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for dropping by, but the codes doesn't work on my end, if i'm not mistaken this will be put on the .htaccess right?! but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the full URL of the CSS files, <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://domain/folder/stylesheet.css">.

And also use the full path for every href links on
that PHP page. Like don't just add `<a href="home.html">`, but instead use `<a href="http://domain/home.html`.